# unable to load layer from Geoserver using OpenJDK16

Tags: java, geoserver

I was using Java 8 and the layer from Geoserver is able to display on my HTML file using OpenLayers 6. But when I changed to OpenJDK 16, there are issues loading the map on my HTML file, attached the error message from Geoserver's console.

I tried to go to Geoserver website, http://geoserver.org/release/stable/, to install some of the plugin/addon, but it didn't work.

> 15 Jul 17:54:13 ERROR [geoserver.ows] -
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class 'Unable to find JDK JPEG
> Writer' is illegal. It must be '{1}' or a derivated class.
> at org.geotools.image.ImageWorker.writeJPEG(ImageWorker.java:3977)
> at org.geoserver.wms.map.JPEGMapResponse.formatImageOutputStream(JPEGMapResponse.java:69)
> at org.geoserver.map.turbojpeg.TurboJPEGMapResponse.formatImageOutputStream(TurboJPEGMapResponse.java:88)
> at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapResponse.write(RenderedImageMapResponse.java:110)
> at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:1029)
> at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:269)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
> at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:70)
> at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
> at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
> at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
> at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:101)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:47)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)

Comment: GeoServer cannot be run using Java 16. https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-10131. The highest Version seems to be Java 12. This is due to the used SpringFramework version.

Answer (score 1):

You should check recommendations regarding Geoserver and Java [docs](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html)